# C# EF Required Attribute not recognized

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, reflection, attributes

I am creating an app that uses a database (SQLite). I am using entity framework and ADO.NET to interact with it.
I have a seprate Models project in my app that contains all of my Database models.

Now I want to mark some of my class properties as required to reflect the "NOT NULL" option in my database. But if I add the [Required] Attribute from DataAnnotations namespace I get a compiler error saying it cannot be resolved.
Here is how my class looks like :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ReflowModels
{
public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        this.Options = new HashSet<Option>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
}
```

I have also added a reference to EntityFramework.dll in my project.

Comment: Did you add reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll?

Comment: Try: [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required], your compiler will tell you if you forget to reference Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,. If the error disappears, then you forgot using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; By the way: what is the exact text of the compiler error?

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I forgot that. Added it and it worked. Thanks for the quick and useful answer :)

Comment: @Kobek if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this to your using block

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

In case it still doesn't work, maybe you should add it to your `References`

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this to your using block

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```